# How to force SetWindowPos to generate WM_SIZE message

Tags: c++, winapi

I found that `SetWindowPos(...hwnd...)` function will not generate WM_SIZE message if the new size is the same as before. But sometimes I need SetWindowPos to generate WM_SIZE message even if the size is not changed. Although I can use `SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SIZE...)` after `SetWindowPos`, but this is a bad solution, since it may generate WM_SIZE twice.

So,

`Is any flag for SetWindowPos or any similar functions so a WM_SIZE message is always generated?`

ps:

I have a main window hwndMain, a child window hwndChild and a child window hwndChild2 of hwndChild.
When hwndMain is resized, it receives WM_SIZE, and there is a MainOnSize(...) function that resize hwndChild. Similarly, if hwndChild is resized, it receives WM_SIZE and there is a ChildOnSize(...) function that resize hwndChild2.

But it comes the case: After hwndMain and hwndChild are created, but not hwndChild2, hwndMain receives WM_SIZE, so hwndMain and hwndChild are resized. Now after hwndChild2 is created, hwndMain still receives a WM_SIZE (see Remark), so it calls MainOnSize to resize hwndChild. But the size of hwndChild is not changed, so it doesn't generate WM_SIZE, and it doesn't call ChildOnsize(), hence hwndChild2 is not resized.

Remark:

The first time hwndMain receives WM_SIZE is when it is created, and the second time is when it is shown by using ShowWindow(...).

Comment: If you are relying on `WM_SIZE` to be called when the size hasn't changed then you are doing it wrong... What is it that you are actually trying to do that would need this?

Comment: +1 on what K-ballo said. It sounds like you are relying on WM_SIZE to be a catch-all indication of when you need to repaint or update other elements.  Knowing what you do when WM_SIZE is caught will lead to some better answers.

Comment: I will explain what I am trying to do in the post.

Comment: So it seems you want to know when a child window is attached to a parent, then?

Comment: Your real problem is that `hwndChild2` is created using the wrong location and dimension. As soon as you create a properly sized window in the right location your problem is gone. To do so handle the [`WM_CREATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632619.aspx) message and modify the [`CREATESTRUCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632603.aspx) as required. It has an `hwndParent` member so you can access the owning window and retrieve its size and location. This should be all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EqualRect` API to determine if `WM_SIZE` will be generated or not by `SetWindowPos` function.

```
bool Window::resize(int x, int y, int width, int height, bool repaint)
{
    UINT flags = SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE;

    if (!repaint)
        flags |= SWP_NOREDRAW;

    RECT requested {
       .left = x,
       .top = y,
       .right = width,
       .bottom = height
    };

    RECT actual;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &actual);

    const bool IsSame = EqualRect(&requested, &actual) != FALSE;
    const bool status = SetWindowPos(mhWnd, HWND_TOP, x, y, width, height, flags) != FALSE;

    if (IsSame)
       SendMessageW(hWnd, WM_SIZE, ...)
   
    return status;
}
```